# Selecting files in a directory based on a list/character, issue with pattern =

Tags: r, directory, copy

I am trying to select files from a "rawimages" folder based on a list comprised of files from another folder. There will be 1000s of this files, I have included one below as an example. The only difference is the RAW images don't have the "_hc" but there are other files in the rawimages folder. See below:

```
ValidateImages <- list.files("C:/Users/JS22/Desktop/Validated")
#example of validated image name: Pia1.2016-10-07.2056+N2009_hc.tif
#Gives list as character value

ToselectfromRAW <- list.files("C:/Users/JS22/Desktop/Raw", pattern = ??ValidateImages??)
#example of raw image name: Pia1.2016-10-07.2056+N2009.tif  

file.copy(from = c(ToselectfromRAW), to = "C:/Users/JS22/Desktop/Training_Set", overwrite = TRUE)
#move the selected images to the desired location
```

I know it has something to do with the 'pattern =' part of the list.files function, but I am unsure as to what. I can change the list to a list with, if helpful:

```
ValidateImages<- as.list(list.files("C:/Users/JS22/Desktop/Validated", all.files = TRUE))
```

Any help would be grand!

(its for use in a randomForest training set fyi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of files in directory and then `grep` which doesn't include the `_hc`:

```
directory <- "C:/Users/JS22/Desktop/Raw"

# remove "_hc.tif" from input filenames to match on
pattern <- gsub("_hc.tif", "", ValidateImages)
pattern <- paste(gsub("([.|()\\^{}+$*?]|\\[|\\])", "\\\\\\1", pattern), collapse="|")

grep(list.files(directory), pattern=pattern, value=TRUE)
```

This outputs the following for provided test files:

```
[1] "Pia1.2016-10-08.0206+N2353_hc.tif" "Pia1.2016-10-08.0248+N752_hc.tif"  "Pia1.2016-10-12.0004+N1976_hc.tif"
[4] "Pia1.2016-10-12.1300+N3159_hc.tif"
```

Comment: Thanks for you response.That would work, but I need to select say 20 specific files from 10,000, so it needs to be based on the validated image name, hence my confusion.

Comment: It should include the files from `ValidateImages`, but without `_hc` prefix?

Comment: Yep, that's why I created the list/character of the desired images to move

Comment: It's possible to just build the pattern from input list, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Great, but then how would I go about moving those images using the file.copy(from = c(ToselectfromRAW), to = "C:/Users/JS22/Desktop/Training_Set", overwrite = TRUE)

Comment: The same, just assign the result of `grep` to some variable and use it inside `file.copy`.

Comment: The grep function returns a empty character value unfortunately

Comment: it only returns the first, doesn't register the |

Comment: Can you share `ValidateImages` and `list.files("C:/Users/JS22/Desktop/Raw")`. At least 10-20 items (better more for raw). So I can have a data to work with.

Comment: yes, I will construct a trail set this evening! Many thanks for your help

Comment: at long last!! Sorry it's taken so long, but I have created a demo set at the following URL. Still not managed to fix it as yet
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ep2lx39ncmstbm/Raw_Image_Extraction.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Jim Did you accept the answer because it works for you? Or you still have issues with it?

Comment: sorry I didn't realise I had! Still having issues, I will remove the resolved tick

Comment: I have updated my answer, I have missed the dots in names, in regex it's mean "any symbol", so it was failing.

Comment: Absolutely great, many thanks for your continued support and patience! I'll let you know when I have the next issue.... Many thanks again. James